# Vuejs data bindings: What is being bound?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, glossary

I'm reading the vuejs docs including http://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html and http://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Binding_Expressions. In simple terms ( for a JS beginner ) can someone explain what is being bound. Also is this connected to the 'v-bind' syntax?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of Vue is that you don't have to update the DOM manually (by adding a new div, or any other element).  The html automatically updates when you change your JS variables.  So for instance, if you have `<span>Hello {{ name }}!</span>` in your code, then you have a corresponding variable in Vue called `name`.  When you update the variable `name`, the contents of that `<span>` automatically update.  So that is "bound" to the javascript variable.

Anytime you see a custom Vue attribute like `v-bind` or `v-on`, the value that you send it is a variable, not a string. For instance, you could use `<button v-bind:disabled="thisIsDisabled">`. Then you need to have a variable in Vue called `thisIsDisabled`, and if it is true the button will be disabled, and if it is false the button will be active. Again, you don't have to update the button to disable or enable it, it's `disabled` attribute will be bound to your variable.

Comment: Thanks again Jeff, that helps me.

Comment: Also is this connected to the 'v-bind' syntax?

Comment: Anytime you see a custom Vue attribute like `v-bind` or `v-on`, the value that you send it is a variable, not a string.  For instance, you could use `<button v-bind:disabled="thisIsDisabled">`.  Then you need to have a variable in Vue called "thisIsDisabled", and if it is true the button will be disabled, and if it is false the button will be active.  Again, you don't have to update the button to disable or enable it, it's `disabled` attribute will be bound to your variable.